# How to install basemap package to Canopy?

Tags: package, canopy, matplotlib-basemap

I tried the following:

1) Open Windows Terminal

2) Change Directory to C:\Users\\Canopy\scripts

3) Type easy_install.exe basemap

4) Wait until the download completes, and restart Enthought

It loaded dependencies and seemed to install, yet when I run Canopy and try to import basemap it says "no module named basemap".

Answer (score 1):

1) If you have a Canopy subscription (paid or free academic), basemap is provided pre-built both in the Full installer and in the Package Manager or via the `enpkg` command-line utility.

2) If you are building it yourself, be sure to see:
https://support.enthought.com/entries/23389761-Installing-packages-into-Canopy-Python-from-the-command-line

3) However you installed it, that's not how it is invoked. Please read the docs. Google is helpful. E.g:
http://matplotlib.org/basemap/api/basemap_api.html
tells you:

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
```